# Secure(r) storage of MySQL login information?

Tags: mysql, security, authentication, password-protection

First off, I realize that there is no such thing as a perfectly secure solution (and even if there were, its usability would be crap).

That said, how do you protect your MySQL database from being compromised by someone downloading your code and picking through it?  Based on my experience with PHP, it seems obligatory to store it within the code at some point or another, which sends up flags for me.  I can see where refactoring to obfuscate variable, constant, and (user-defined) function names could be beneficial, but in the end it'd still be possible to trace through it and find the file with the DB login information.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the MySQL auth information is stored in an *external* configuration file. The MySQL user  used by the web-based app is given limited permissions such as `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE` and not given permissions such as `ALTER, DROP, DELETE`. If you want to release the code to the public you would not include your private config file, but a generic/instructional/minimal config file instead.

Storing the MySQL auth info in an encrypted format is somewhat silly, as you'd need to store the private key / unencryption locally as well. If it is trivial for an unauthenticated user to view the code or configuration files on your server the problem isn't the code - it's your server setup & config.

Answer (score 1):

Security can be assisted by storing any hard-coded information (in config files or scripts) outside of the web-root, and by suppressing (on the production code) error messages. That way, hopefully, your users won't see that `userValidate() expects exactly three paramaters`.

Answer (score 1):

pygorex1 is correct, you should use external configuration files where "external" means a file outside the web root. So even if there would be a configuration error in your web server which would allow the user to see your source code, they would not be able to see the database credentials since they cannot be accessed directly via the browser.

pygorex1 is also right on the user permissions. Limiting the mysql user's access to a minimum is always preferred. Even if a hacker would get the your mysql password and username, he would not be able to do significant damage if the user permissions are only limited to eg SELECT-queries. One thing he forgot to mention was that the mysql user should only be allowed to log in from localhost (or from whatever host the web application is on), never use wildcards in the allowed hosts.